# jQuery adding img tag and wrapped

Tags: jquery

I have a div tag

```
<img class="example" src="http://adress.pl/img/oryginal.jpg" align="left">
```

I want to add a tag.
End result:

```
<a href="http://adress.pl/img/oryginal.jpg" rel="example_group">
   <img src="http://adress.pl/cache.php?f=oryginal.jpg&w=200&h=100" width="200px" height="100px" class="example">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrap the element and [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the height and width attributes

```
$('.example').wrap(function () {
    return $('<a />', {
        href: $(this).attr('src'),
        align: 'left'
    })
}).attr({
    height: '100px',
    width: '200px',
    src : function(idx, src){
        var parts = src.split('/');
        return 'http://adress.pl/cache.php?f=' + parts[parts.length - 1] +'&w=200&h=100'
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/83wug/)

Comment: Thank you very much.
I want to replace the img tag => src = "http://adress.pl/cache.php?f=oryginal.jpg&w=200&h=100"
The example given in the topic.

Comment: I have one problem.
This code works very well. The problem is that the original images against jquery load fine normally. Is it possible to wczytywało thumbnails at once? : http://adress.pl/cache.php?f=oryginal.jpg&w=200&h=100 -------------- I use the "$ (document). Ready (function () {" to load js.